# What is the right way to rotate a camera widget?

Tags: python, kivy

XCamera widget which extends Camera widget is rotated by 90 degrees on smartphones.

I've seen people saying the below works but not for me:

```
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Rotate, PopMatrix, PushMatrix
from kivy_garden.xcamera import XCamera
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

builder = Builder.load_string('''
<MyCam>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    XCamera:
        play: True
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: -90
            origin: self.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
''')

class MyCam(XCamera):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return builder

TestApp().run()
```

**Update:**

The builder variable in example above returns None because at the point when it's created it doesn't know what MyCam class is yet.

This code works as desired but **not with extended XCamera widget**:

```
class MyCam(Camera):
    pass

builder = Builder.load_string('''
BoxLayout:
    MyCam:
        resolution: 1280, 720
        play: True
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix:
            Rotate:
                angle: -90
                axis: 0,0,1
                origin: root.width/2, root.height/2
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix:
''')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return builder

TestApp().run()
```

When I use `XCamera` instead of `Camera` the app crashes without Python-related error in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `builder` is None, so your app doesn't display anything.

There doesn't look to be anything wrong with the canvas code, except in that this crude rotation about the origin may not be very practical to fit with other app elements. It would be better to manipulate the tex_coords of the Rectangle displaying the camera image, and also manipulate the Rectangle shape to stay appropriately within the widget bounds, but this would require subtler modifications of the camera internals.

Comment: Don't edit your question to turn it into a different question. When the question changes, ask it separately.

Comment: Also your assertion that "The builder variable in example above returns None because at the point when it's created it doesn't know what MyCam class is yet." is wrong, it returns None because there's no root widget definition, not because the MyCam class isn't defined yet.

Comment: OK. So I still know nothing about Kivy development.

Comment: I thought `MyCam` is a root widget in my example.

Comment: `<MyCam>` defines a _rule_ for how every `MyCam` should be constructed. The MyCam instance is the root of that rule. But `Builder.load_string` returns (if anything) the specific root widget definition from the kv string, which is a unique rule of the form `MyCam:` (without the `<>`) that defines how a single specific widget tree should be structured.